# Kendo SPA View not updating with MVVM when updating ViewModel after Ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm, kendo-view, kendo-spa

I'm working on a SPA app based on Kendo UI but having trouble with Views not updating.

1. The main layout has a grid filled with Quotes and a load action allowing the user to load the quote for viewing/editing
2. Loading the quote is done using Ajax, downloading the HTML for the SPA View as well as the ViewModel which is populated using the standard this.set("property", value) syntax
3. Once the HTML and ViewModel are loading I use the Kendo Router to show the next view which **Correctly** shows the HTML view with data in the input fields
4. If I then click back and choose a different quote to load, the data is coming back (confirmed via Firebug), the ViewModel is correctly updated (also confirmed via Firebug) but the HTML inputs aren't updated for some reason.

Am I supposed to be refreshing the View manually somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I might be a lil late with the answer but hope this helps. After the ajax success just trigger the change event for the ViewModel property as such:

```
viewModel.trigger("change", { field: "fieldName" });
```